# Did the spamming counter-attack on The DAO attack work to slow down the attacks?

Tags: security, the-dao, attacks

This question was asked in the comment section of [What does TheDAO counter-attack by spamming actually do? (suggested by Stephan Tual)](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/6169/what-does-thedao-counter-attack-by-spamming-actually-do-suggested-by-stephan-t).

Background links:

- The attacks used a recursive call vulnerability as described in [What is a recursive calling vulnerability?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/6176/what-is-a-recursive-calling-vulnerability).
- You can find a list of the accounts used in [Which accounts are involved in mounting the recursive call vulnerability attacks on The DAO?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/6224/which-accounts-are-involved-in-mounting-the-recursive-call-vulnerability-attacks).
- You can find the period when the attacks occurred in [Is there any way to determine how long it took for the DAO attacker to deploy the attack?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/6174/is-there-any-way-to-determine-how-long-it-took-for-the-dao-attacker-to-deploy-th?lq=1).

Did the spamming counter-attack on The DAO attack work to slow down the attacks?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the account [0x969837498944ae1dc0dcac2d0c65634c88729b2d](http://etherscan.io/txs?a=0x969837498944ae1dc0dcac2d0c65634c88729b2d), you will see that there were 277 attack transactions. From the listing, you will see that there were 9 failed transactions on the last page. (There were a few early in the attack as well.)

The [last successful transaction](http://etherscan.io/tx/0x8471497131d77305416c760ebfed2b6d653c2066c51dac58c6551dcc7dfb3350) before the set of 9 failed transaction in block [1720231](http://etherscan.io/block/1720231) had a gas usage of 2890937.

The first unsuccessful transaction in the set of 9 failed transaction in block [1720316](http://etherscan.io/block/1720316) had a gas usage of 4273000. This block had a gas limit of  4712388 and a gas usage of  4710819.

From this information and the gas usage being close to the gas limit in blocks [1720337](http://etherscan.io/block/1720337) to [1720426](http://etherscan.io/block/1720426) containing the series of 9 failed attack transaction, I would guess that the other transactions on the block used up the block's gas usage towards the block's gas limit, causing the attacker's transaction to fail.

However, I could not find any transactions (from my brief look) generated by the friendly's spamming attack using the code listed in [What does TheDAO counter-attack by spamming actually do? (suggested by Stephan Tual)](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/6169/what-does-thedao-counter-attack-by-spamming-actually-do-suggested-by-stephan-t):

```
for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) { 
    eth.sendTransaction({from: eth.accounts[0], gas: 2300000,
      gasPrice: web3.toWei(20, “shannon”), 
      data: “0x5b620186a05a131560135760016020526000565b600080601f600039601f565b6000f3”}) }
}
```

And looking at the blocks around the time of the series of 9 of the attacker's failed transactions, there were quite a number of blocks with 0 transactions, e.g. block [1720318](http://etherscan.io/block/1720318).

The other attacking account [0xf35e2cc8e6523d683ed44870f5b7cc785051a77d](http://etherscan.io/txs?a=0xf35e2cc8e6523d683ed44870f5b7cc785051a77d) had only one failure early on, so the transactions from this account were not affected by the friendly's spamming transaction.

**Conclusion**:

My results are inconclusive.

- Only a small portion of the attacker's attacking transactions failed and these may have been caused by other transactions filling up the block's gas usage.
- And there were some blocks with 0 transactions around the time of the failure.
- And the was no sign of the friendly's spamming transactions around the time of the failures.